# ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin out of memory (Solution)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

It took me awhile to find a solid answer for this so I figured I would put the solution on here. Upgrading node caused an issue when I would save in React as my project was running. As it was reloading it would get this error.

```
Type checking and linting aborted - probably out of memory. Check `memoryLimit` option in ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin configuration.
```

I would have to stop the host and run npm start everytime. All the solutions online said to increase the memory, but they don't say where and neither does the documentation. It would not be an issue if the wepback.config wasn't such a big file like mine is so its hard to understand where this code is implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Solution:

Open your webpack.config file and find this area, then add the memoryLimit (for me it was not there by default) and specify a new amount (I doubled it just to be safe) and then save the file and you should be good to go!

```
new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
  async: false,
  watch: paths.appSrc,
  tsconfig: paths.appTsConfig,
  tslint: paths.appTsLint,
  memoryLimit: 5000,
}),
```

Answer (score 1):

Another idea:

If your project is not huge (or it has used to work in the past), then chances are high that you are linting/compiling the folders that are not supposed to. (e.g. `/dist` or any folder that has compiled artifacts.)

I would recommend running `tsc` and `eslint` individually (preferably with `- debug` option) to see if they are doing their job properly and only compiling/linting the source code.